# Do data transformations count as being part of the Model or is that part of the controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, api-design

As a simplified example,  let's say we have model1 and model2 that return some data.  Then, we take those things returned by model1 and model2 and transform them to create a new thing and return that thing.  Is that transformation process part of the model (the M in MVC) or is that transformation process better suited to being part of the controller (the C in MVC)?

For instance is this:

```
def controller():
    data1 = model1.getData()
    data2 = model2.getData()
    data3 = new model3(data1, data2).getData()
    return data3
```

better than this?

```
def controller():

    def transform_data(data1, data2):
         return something

    data1 = model1.getData()
    data2 = model2.getData()
    data3 = transform_data(data1, data2)
    return data3
```

Thoughts?

Comment: try to think about in a bit different way: controller is supposed to change the model state (and nothing more). and if the purpose of the controller from your exapmle is to operate on model3, it does not really need to know anything about model1 and model2, it's model3's responsibility to pull some data from them.

Comment: i've seen your another question 'Do backend web service API's have a view as in MVC?'. Good thing to think of and to have as an example. Let's say you press a button on the web page. This is a user input to the view. Some code is attached to handle that click event. That is some controller that is subscribed to listen to the view and handle user input. Controller sends the request to server. That is controller operating the model. Does this controller know anything about 'multiple' models? It surely doesn't. And then (after response came) the view updates itself (with model's data).